# Removing <a href > tag using regex

Tags: html, regex

I want to extract the plain text from given HTML code. I tried using `regex` and got

`String target = val.replaceAll("<a.*</a>", "");`.

My main requirement is I want remove everything between `<a>` and  `</a>` (including the Link name). While using the above code all other contents also removed.

`<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>` **This is a Google Link**

`<a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>` **This is a Yahoo Link**

Here I want to remove the values between `<a>` and `</a>`. 
Final output should

`This is a Google Link  This is a Yahoo Link`

Comment: [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: This is what jQuery is good at.

Comment: What's the leading "String" for? Is this Javascript?

Comment: In Javascript, wouldn't this be something more like `var clean_string = my_string.replace(/<a.*?<\/a>/i,'');`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier (`*?`). For example, to remove the link entirely:

```
String target = val.replaceAll("<a.*?</a>", "");
```

Or to replace the link with just the link tag's contents:

```
String target = val.replaceAll("<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>", "This is a $1 Link");
```

However, I would still recommend using a proper DOM manipulation API.