# Java - How to remove angle brackets and text between from a string

Tags: java, android, string

I would like to remove all the occurrences of angle brackets and the text in between, from my string. So given the following:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_%28series%29">Grand Theft Auto</a> is a video game series created and primarily developed by Scottish developer Rockstar North, published in 1998.
```

I need this:

```
Grand Theft Auto is a video game series created and primarily developed by Scottish developer Rockstar North, published in 1998.
```

I have tried using the following, which doesn't seems to change the original string at all:

```
string.replaceAll("<.*?>","");
```

Comment: Did you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867719/removing-a-href-tag-using-regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java strings are **immutable**, and **don't change by themselves**. You need to change them. Change this:

```
string.replaceAll("<.*?>","");
```

To this:

```
string = string.replaceAll("<.*?>","");
```

Comment: I cant believe I made such a basic mistake

Comment: Yes. Your logic was completely correct. A silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String str = string.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
```

Edit: Correction made @John Hascall comment.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained *why* that regex.  (And BTW, I think your regex is wrong.)  Consider an input: `Hello<p>blah<span>bleah</span>blurgh</p>World`  -- This is why the original RE had the non-greedy qualifier `?`

Answer (score 0):

```
String tmp = yourString.replaceAll("<a.*?>", "");
String finalString = tmp.replaceAll("</a>,"");
System.out.print(finalString);
```

Comment: Was about to comment that it would not compile :)

Comment: Lol, I noticed 1 second before than you :P